# How to sort days of the week in a pivot table in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

In Superset, I would like to be able to create a pivot table based on activity by day of the week.  This can be achieved, however the days are sorted alphabetically (Friday, Monday, ..., Wednesday).  How should I create the pivot table so that the days of the week are sorted in their natural order?

My hack to achieve this was to add the number of the day to the start of the string `CONCAT(MOD(DAYOFWEEK(timestamp)+5, 7)+1, ": ", DAYNAME(timestamp)) AS day`.  This gives, for example, "1: Monday".  When Superset sorts this alphabetically, the days are at least in their correct order.

Is there a way to achieve a natural day ordering without relying on this hack?

[image: Pivot table with hack]